# hypersurface in space R^4

Tags: linear-algebra

I have this task and I do not know what to do- in other words i am stuck.

Let In Space $\mathbb R^4$ there is defined hypersurface, which  includes only those vectors whose standard basis coordinates $(x_1; x_2; x_3; x_4)$, makes this true: $x_1^2+x_2^2-x_3^2-x_4^2=1$.

Find hypersurface equation basis $f: f_1=(1;1;1;1), f_2=(1;1;-1;-1), f_3=(1;-1;1;-1), f_4=(1;-1;-1;1)$ in coordinates $(x1';x2';x3';x4')$

How should I proceed?

Also not so relevant question: I am new here, I cant seem to write math formulas, how is it done?

Comment: See [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) about writing math formulas

Comment: Duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3162932/265466, which hasn’t been answered yet.